# nginx serve static files such as .py or other files

Tags: nginx

I'm using nginx as my server and want to serve some static files, mostly code files, such as .py .java files. but when I do this, nginx directly make the browser download the files as visit

http://localhost:8001/test.py

I know that should be Conten-Type , but I've already configured. below is part of sample nginx config file.

```
default_type text/plain;
server {
    listen       8001;
    server_name  localhost;

    location /  {
        add_header Content-Type text/plain;
        root /path/to/files/;
    }
}
```

so, how to make the browser directly display the file instead of download? Just use nginx static serve or need add some configs?
thx a lot.

Comment: why Content-Type text/plain?

Comment: I want to force files to be Content-Type text/plain instead of  applcation/octet-stream

Answer (score 1):

ok, I know how to do that.just forgot to do that :(

just add the config

autoindex on;

to server or location section in nginx.
that's waht I want.

Comment: could you edit to improve your answer in terms of formatting and some more details